# Checkboxgroup getting duplicates value on second call

Tags: extjs

I am displaying checkboxgroup on a window with other fields too.
But the second time I call the function to display this window with the checkboxgroup the checkboxgroup gets duplicated.

i.e It only displays two times and not multiple times.

Eg : If actual checkbox values are "red" , "green" then the result on second ,third  call will be "red" , "red" , "green" , "green".

Even the +Checklist button displays twice on second or more calls.

It displays proper values on first call though.

below is the code I am working on.

```
 var checkboxconfigs = [];
          function showassetForm(record,statusname,emptyval) 
            {
            var arrSubTicket = getSubTickets(record.data.Id);

        for(z=0;z<arrSubTicket.length;z++)
           {
                checkboxconfigs.push({ //pushing into array
               id:arrSubTicket[z].Id,
               boxLabel:arrSubTicket[z].Name,
               name:'checklist',
               inputValue:arrSubTicket[z].Id,
               relatedTicket:arrSubTicket[z].TicketId
        //any other checkbox properties, layout related or whatever
        });
           }


        var  myCheckboxGroup = Ext.create('Ext.form.CheckboxGroup', {
            columns: 1,
            vertical: true,
            items: checkboxconfigs
        });
         myCheckboxGroup.on({              
            change: function(checkboxGroup, newValue) {
                 formattedValues = [];

                newValue = newValue.checklist.length === 0 ? [newValue.checklist] : newValue.checklist;
                checkboxGroup.items.each(function(checkbox){
                    var checkboxValue = checkbox.inputValue,
                        foramttedValue = {};

                    foramttedValue[checkboxValue] = newValue.indexOf(checkboxValue) !== -1 ? 'on' : 'off';

                    formattedValues.push(foramttedValue);
                });
            }

        });



             form = Ext.widget('form', {
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                border: false,
                bodyPadding: 10,

                fieldDefaults: {
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    labelWidth: 100,
                    labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold'
                },
                defaults: {
                    margins: '0 0 10 0'
                },



                items: [{
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;padding:0',
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    defaultType: 'textfield',

                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelAlign: 'left'
                    },

                    items: [
                    /*{
                        flex: 1,
                        name: 'Name',
                        fieldLabel: 'Ticket Description',
                        allowBlank: true
                    },*/ 
                    {

                        name: 'Hours',
                        fieldLabel: 'Hours',
                        allowBlank: true,
                        value: record.data.Hours
                    }, 

                    {    
                         flex: 2, 
                        xtype:'textarea',
                        name: 'Notes',
                        fieldLabel: 'Ticket Notes',
                        allowBlank: true
                    }, 
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        fieldLabel: 'Status',
                        hiddenName: 'Status',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        name:'Status',
                        store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
                            data: allstatus,
                            id: 0,
                            fields: ['value', 'text']
                        }),
                       // valueField: 'value',
                        valueField: 'value',
                        displayField: 'text',
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        editable: false,
                       // value : record.data.Status
                        value : statusname
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        fieldLabel: 'Priority',
                        hiddenName: 'Priority',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        name:'Priority',
                        store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
                            data: priorities,
                            id: 0,
                            fields: ['value', 'text']
                        }),
                       // valueField: 'value',
                        valueField: 'value',
                        displayField: 'text',
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        editable: false,
                        value : record.data.Priority
                    },

                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        id: 'newSubTicket',
                        cls:'x-btn-default-small',
                        text: '+ Checklist',
                        handler : function () {
                            createSubticket(record,statusname);
                        },
                        style : 'margin:0 0px'
                    },

                    myCheckboxGroup

                    ]
                }],

                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Cancel',

                    handler: function() {                        
                        this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                        this.up('window').hide();
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'Save',
                    handler: function() {
                           if (this.up('form').getForm().isValid()) 
                           {
                            // In a real application, this would submit the form to the configured url
                            // this.up('form').getForm().submit();
                           form =  this.up('form').getForm();
                           var recordsToAdd = [],recordsToAddNotes = [];
                           var record1 = {},recordNotes = {};
                            //this.up('window').hide();
                            //var summary = form.findField('Name').getSubmitValue();
                            var hrs = form.findField('Hours').getSubmitValue();
                            var status = form.findField('Status').getSubmitValue();
                            var priority = form.findField('Priority').getSubmitValue();
                            var notes = form.findField('Notes').getSubmitValue();
                            record1['ccfive_related_ticket_status']=status;
                            record1['dev_priority']=priority;
                            record1['io_uuid'] = record.data.Id;
                            //console.log("TicketName="+record.data.TicketName);
                            recordsToAdd.push(record1);

                            recordNotes['dev_note'] = notes;
                            recordNotes['dev_hours'] = hrs;
                            recordNotes['dev_related_punchlist_item'] = record.data.Id;
                            recordNotes['ccfive_related_ticket_status'] = status;
                            recordsToAddNotes.push(recordNotes);

                        }
                    }
                }]
            });

            win = Ext.widget('window', {
                title: record.data.TicketName,
                closeAction: 'hide',
                width: 400,
                height: 450,
                minHeight: 220,
                layout: 'fit',
                resizable: true,
                modal: true,
                items: form
            });
            win.show();

 }
```

[This is what I get on first call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THz9g.png)

But after clicking on cancel and calling the function it displays me.

[Duplicate checkboxes and checklist button on second call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNArk.png)

Comment: Can you post an image of what you see, as well as the rendered HTML from that visual image (by inspecting the outer HTML element of the image?

Comment: What happens if you put an additional `checkboxconfigs = []` as the first line in `showassetForm`? It looks as if the array is reused and refilled, but not emptied.

Comment: @Alexander I tried using checkboxconfigs = [] but that doesnt helps.

Comment: @Alexander also it only displays twice , and not multiple times.Even if called fourth or fifth time it just displays two times.

Comment: @MacGyver Added Image

Comment: @Alexander Also the checkboxconfigs array do not have duplicates , its only the checkboxgroup that is duplicated.

Comment: @coolbuddy You're obviously not calling `showassetForm` from the code sample you provided; and you're obviously not clearing the array in the code sample you provided. To find the problem we need all info we can get.

Comment: @Alexander I am calling showassetForm  in my real code and clearing the array too.This is the sample link to the code file https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzv1szxdr8i7o08/newhtml.html?dl=0   Save the file on your machine and when you run it double click on any of the boxes and it will open up a popup.Then press the cancel button.Again click on the box and the items will be duplicated.

Comment: Seems weird to me , any help really appreciated.

Comment: @Alexander did you looked into it?

Comment: Can you paste the rendered HTML please?  Go to Google Chrome > Click Settings icon (top right corner of browser) > more tools > developer tools > copy the HTML section of the page after the page displays and paste in your question.  We need to be able to see the "id" property of your elements.  Many times, ExtJS components render weird if the id property isn't unique.  It's always risky to give your own ids.  Try and avoid it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @MacGyver , you just made my day.I was really struggling hard for it.The issues was with passing id property to element.Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Move var checkboxconfigs = []; into showassetForm function

```
function showassetForm(record, statusname, emptyval) {
var checkboxconfigs = [];
var arrSubTicket = getSubTickets(record.data.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was just of passing id to some parameters on form.
Extjs sometimes behaves weird if Id is passed.
Removed id parameter and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try and avoid duplicate ids (see comment "double check this"):

```
for(z=0;z<arrSubTicket.length;z++)
{
  checkboxconfigs.push({
  id:arrSubTicket[z].Id,  // <==================== double check this!!
  boxLabel:arrSubTicket[z].Name,
  name:'checklist',
  inputValue:arrSubTicket[z].Id,  // <============ double check this!!
  relatedTicket:arrSubTicket[z].TicketId
});
```